# Saw an interesting command but can't alias it

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc, alias, functions

Saw an command from [this post to *Generate a list of available commands and what each does*](https://askubuntu.com/a/266839/75967) that I would like to alias

```
find {,/usr}/{,s}bin -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 whatis | sort | less
```

I assume the `less` or the `|` is interfering but how can I make the alias command ignore those characters that is causing it issues?

ie. This doesn't work

```
alias cccc='find {,/usr}/{,s}bin -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 whatis | sort | less'
cccc
```

It returns

```
    pell0modem-manager0airserv-ng0usermod0vipw0filefrag0update-software-center0ntpdate-
debian0usbmuxd0foomatic-extract-text0cupsenable0dpkg-divert0dpkg-preconfigure0foomatic-
getpjloptions0ldattach0hplj10200bccmd0vpnc-disconnect0madwifi-
unload0cupsd0tcpd0hplj10180pppstats0service0update-icon-caches0atieventsd0hpljP15050grub-
set-default0userdel0arpd0gpsdctl0remove-shell0cpgr0winbindd0cracklib-format0update-catalog0wesside-ng0vmware-authdlauncher0aireplay-ng0install-docs0hciattach0lpc0install-menu0ck-log-system-restart0foomatic-printermap-to-gutenprint-xml0setvesablank0gconf-schemas0airmon-ng0zic0update-apt-xapian-index0pm-suspend0rebuild-
```

Instead of

```
[ (1)                - check file types and compare values
2to3 (1)             - Python2 to Python3 converter
2to3-2.7 (1)         - Python2 to Python3 converter
2to3-3.2 (1)         - Python2 to Python3 converter
411toppm (1)         - convert Sony Mavica .411 image to ppm
7z (1)               - A file archiver with highest compression ratio
7za (1)              - A file archiver with highest compression ratio
a2p (1)              - Awk to Perl translator
accept (2)           - accept a connection on a socket
accessdb (8)         - dumps the content of a man-db database in a human read...
aclocal-1.11 (1)     - manual page for aclocal 1.11.6
aclocal (1)          - manual page for aclocal 1.11.3
```

when you execute the command by itself.

#### After the Fact - Supplemental

I also added another useful function for myself to query via a string against that catalogue of commands.

```
fff() { 
   find {,/usr}/{,s}bin -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 whatis |& grep $1
}
```

So if you type the command `fff pdf` it will show you all the related commands about pdf like this

```
pdfunite (1)         - Portable Document Format (PDF) page merger
ps2pdf13 (1)         - Convert PostScript to PDF 1.3 (Acrobat 4-and-later com...
pdftotext (1)        - Portable Document Format (PDF) to text converter (vers...
ps2pdfwr (1)         - Convert PostScript to PDF without specifying Compatibi...
pdfdetach (1)        - Portable Document Format (PDF) document embedded file ...
ps2pdf (1)           - Convert PostScript to PDF using ghostscript
ps2pdf12 (1)         - Convert PostScript to PDF 1.2 (Acrobat 3-and-later com...
pdf2dsc (1)          - generate a PostScript page list of a PDF document
pdfimages (1)        - Portable Document Format (PDF) image extractor (versio...
pdftoppm (1)         - Portable Document Format (PDF) to Portable Pixmap (PPM...
foomatic-ppdfile (1) - Generate a PPD file for a given printer/driver combo
dvipdf (1)           - Convert TeX DVI file to PDF using ghostscript and dvips
qpdf (1)             - PDF transformation software
pdftocairo (1)       - Portable Document Format (PDF) to PNG/JPEG/PDF/PS/EPS/...
pdfseparate (1)      - Portable Document Format (PDF) page extractor
pdftops (1)          - Portable Document Format (PDF) to PostScript converter...
ps2pdf14 (1)         - Convert PostScript to PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5-and-later com...
pdfinfo (1)          - Portable Document Format (PDF) document information ex...
pdftohtml (1)        - program to convert PDF files into HTML, XML and PNG im...
pdfopt (1)           - Ghostscript PDF Optimizer
pdffonts (1)         - Portable Document Format (PDF) font analyzer (version ...
pdf2ps (1)           - Ghostscript PDF to PostScript translator
```

I think this is kind of useful for knowing all the commands that are available

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't bother around with aliases for more complicated stuff, use a shell function instead:

```
 function cccc() {
    find {,/usr}/{,s}bin -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 whatis | sort | less
 }
```

See `man bash` for the justification:

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat confusing. Bash always reads at least one complete
>   line of input before executing any of the commands on that line. Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it
>   is executed. Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does not take effect until the
>   next line of input is read. The commands following the alias definition on that line are not affected by the new alias.
>   This behavior is also an issue when functions are executed. Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not
>   when the function is executed, because a function definition is itself a compound command. As a consequence, aliases
>   defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed. To be safe, always put alias definitions on
>   a separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands.

Comment: So I add this to .bashrc?

Comment: The same place as before with the alias approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can alias it properly if you substitute the backslash `\` with the proper string code `\\`. The right alias would be:

```
alias cccc="find {,/usr}/{,s}bin -printf '%f\\0' | xargs -0 whatis | sort | less"
```