# How to redirect all manuals to files?

Tags: command-line, bash, manpage, redirect

Just for fun, or say for sake of convenience, I decided to write out all man pages to files.

Now if I have to do it one by one, I would do `man package-name > filename`.  But I want to do some smart work and write all mans at once, either by using single command or by a bash script.All that I have come up with till now is

```
cd /usr/share #you may use any folder
whereis -m * | grep '.gz' |awk '{print$1}' |sed s/://g
```

This gives an output, naming all applications having man pages.Some part of it is as below.

```
speech-dispatcher
stellarium
synaptic
syslinux
system-config-printer
tabset
terminfo
totem
ufw
unetbootin
unity
unity-greeter
update-manager
upstart
usb_modeswitch
vim
virtualbox
vlc
xmms2
xpdf
yelp
zenity
```

Now, what I need to do is redirect this output to `man` so that I could redirect it to files.Once I do this, then I may create a script to *cd* to every folder and check for *mans*.

So my question is, how do I achieve this?

OR, maybe an alternate way exists?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

> Please migrate it to stackoverflow if it's appropriate there.Though I think it's more appropriate here.

Comment: Look into `mandb` and `accessdb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many executables in `/bin`. If you want to copy their corresponding man pages into files, you use something like this in your terminal

```
for f in /bin/*;do man $(basename $f) > $HOME/man_$(basename $f); done
```

After execution of the command you will find all the man pages corresponds to the executables in `/bin/` in your home. For example man page corresponds to `ls` will take name `man_ls.txt` inyour home.

If you want copy only a part, say the executables name begins with `r`, use,

```
for f in /bin/r*;do man $(basename $f) > $HOME/man_$(basename $f); done
```

You may get several note like,

```
No manual entry for <some_executable>
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

for the executables which does not have a man entry.

Do this for other folders which contains executables like, `/usr/bin/` ,`/usr/sbin/` ,`/sbin/` etc.

**Note:**

you can use `2>/dev/null` with your command to suppress the error messages for executables without man entry. like,

```
for f in /usr/bin/r*;do man $(basename $f) > $HOME/man_$(basename $f) 2>/dev/null; done
```

---

**According to your approach**

Navigate to a folder and use this for the same result,

```
for f in $(whereis -m * | grep '.gz' |awk '{print$1}' |sed s/://g); do man $f > $HOME/man_$f.txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, *why* would you want a file containing all the man pages? If it is to facilitate searching through all of them for some keyword, GNU already provides `apropos` for just that:

```
apropos some-regular-expression
```

returns a list of all man pages matching the regular expression in their name or description.

Anyway, if you still want the encyclopedic file, then making use of apropos, you can obtain a list of all man pages on the system by searching for the universal regular expression:

```
apropos '.*'
```

then feed the resulting list into the `man` command:

```
apropos '.*' | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs man > all-manpages.txt
```

You could also use the method described in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/266839/134479) to the similar question ["Generate a list of all available commands and what each does"](https://askubuntu.com/q/266735/134479), replacing `whatis` by `man`.

Comment: I don't want all in one.I thought I could just surf through them and then I can possibly find some command or option I never knew about.